# How can I create a zero DateTime with php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to create an empty date with DateTime(). So, all zeros. The time should be displayed in that way: `0000:00:0:00:00`.

What I have tried:

```
$date = new DateTime("2019-05-09 12:07");
$date->setTime(0, 0);
$date->setDate(0, 0, 0);
echo $date->format("Y:W:j:H:i");
```

That outputs

```
-0001:49:30:00:00
```

instead of `0000:00:0:00:00`

What could I do to achieve a zero datetime?

Comment: If you open a calendar you could see that we never had a zero day, month or year. You can't create such date.

Comment: @Dharman, zero year is possible (I was there :() with `$date->setDate(0, 1, 1);` you get `0000:01:01:00:00`

Answer (score 2):

More an explanation of what is going wrong than how to achieve what you are after - even if it is possible.

From a date point of view - 0 is invalid for both the month and day.  In the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php) it has the example

> Example #2 Values exceeding ranges are added to their parent values

So if you have greater than the number of days in a month, it will make it the next month

In your case it is almost the opposite, having a number less than the start of the month.  So 0 as the month and day, it will act as -1, so if you formatted it as

```
echo $date->format("Y:m:d:H:i");
```

the output is

```
-0001:11:30:00:00
```

So as you can see, the day and month are 0-1 (11 and 30) and this has overflowed into the year with -1.

Comment: So, is there no way to create a zero datetime?

Comment: As day and month cannot be zero, I would think it is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot make a datetime `0000:00:0:00:00` from `DateTime()`

```
php > echo (new DateTime("0000-00-00 00:00:00"))->format("Y-W-j H:i");
-0001-49-30 00:00
php > echo (new DateTime())->setISODate(0,0,0)->setTime(0,0,0,0)->format("Y-W-j H:i");
-0001-52-26 00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely Not..!
although you can create any Date with PHP helper function (that uses DateTime class behind) any of you desire date with Zeor Time only

```
$date = date_create('now'); // or any '1970-01-01'
$date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d 00:00:00');
// or
$date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('2021-12-21'));
// or
$date = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

output: "2021-12-21 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize the time with current time and take difference of the current time after. its a trick you can perfom to get (0000-00-00 00:00:00).

```
$currentTime = new DateTime('NOW');

$diff = $currentTime->diff(new DateTime('NOW'));
echo $diff->format("%Y-%m-%d %H %i %s");
```

that will give you 0000-00-00 00:00:00